# Решить задачу по SQL по базе Northwind (решил, но есть сомнения)

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Сколькими наименованиями товаров торговал каждый продавец в 1997 году? (подзапрос)

В таблице `[order details]` есть список заказов (`OrderID`) и список c `ID` продуктов (`ProductID`), но в
заказах продукты могут повторятся, поэтому при подсчете по столбцу продуктов следовало использовать `distinct`?

```
select orders.employeeID, count(distinct  productid)
from [Order Details] 
join orders on [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
where 
    [Order Details].orderid in (
            select orderid
            from Orders
            where year(OrderDate) = 1997
        )
group by orders.employeeID
```

Comment: что-то у меня сомнения что вы подзапрос в нужное место написали. Если в задаче подзарос требуется, то возможно в каком то другом смысле. напримре подзапрос в select выражении, а не в where

Comment: *решил, но есть сомнения* Правильно. Оптимальности никакой, зато избыточности в достатке. Зачем вообще тут нужен подзапрос? просто `left join orders on [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID and year(OrderDate) = 1997`.

Comment: решить через подзапрос было условием самой задачи

Comment: Тогда вместо таблицы orders используйте подзапрос с условием по году, и уже его left join вместо таблицы.

Comment: @Akina следуя терминологии, `from (select ...) as t` это не подзапрос, а производная таблица.

Comment: я думаю тут надо сделать `select id, (select count()..... ) from employee`

Comment: @teran Ну коррелированный подзапрос в SELECT тогда... только не забыть COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina вряд ли в данном задании подразумевалось использование COALESCE т.к. тема была именно по подзапросам. В лекциях решали задачи способом, который предложил teran, но я пока не додумался как решить задачу таким способом

Comment: а чего тут задумываться то, у вас есть `e.id` из основного запроса, вот и передайте его в подзапрос, выбрав там `(seelct count(distinct product_id) from orders where o.employee_id = e.id and y = 2017` ну или что-то подобное

Comment: *вряд ли в данном задании подразумевалось использование COALESCE т.к. тема была именно по подзапросам.* DISTINCT тоже не входит в тему лекции - однако это как-то не помешало его использовать, верно? Без Coalesce - никуда не деться с коррелированным подзапросом, он  же может не обнаружить соответствующих записей и вернуть пустой набор.

Comment: @teran count(distinct product_id) не выйдет, т.к. productid нет в таблице orders 
P.S. Я первый месяц в SQL, так что мне еще долго будет о чем задумываться)